# MySQL Event Not Running

Tags: mysql

This is the first time I created a event and for some reason, my event worked well after the datetime set in `Starts` field, but somehow, it did not run at 12-09, 12-10 and 12-11!

The event only calls a stored procedure (which works properly well btw).
Is there any config missing in my event?

[image]

Comment: "The global event_scheduler system variable determines whether the Event Scheduler is enabled and running on the server. It has one of these 3 values, which affect event scheduling as described here:"   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html

Comment: How can I see if this var is set as `on`@RaymondNijland? Probably that's the reason of error.

Comment: `SELECT @@event_scheduler`  would show if it on or off

Comment: It was Off @RaymondNijland!! But i remember running this code `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` but it wasn't effective for more than 1 day? This query only affects the session?

Comment: SET GLOBAL affects all sessions but you need SUPER privilege for this. And if you restart the server event_scheduler will be Off again. So it's better to add event_scheduler to the MySQL's config also.

Comment: Awesome @RaymondNijland, and which file do i have to add this configuration??

Comment: Can't really answer that.. Information should be in here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Comment: Thanks Raymond, that worked! Please answer my question so I can accept it